# how to pad with different spaces based on the length of previous column in notepad++/vim/sed

Tags: vim, sed, notepad++

How to pad with different spaces based on the length of previous column in notepad++/vim/sed?

For example:

```
123      456
1   456
233   555
232233   32323

=>

123      456
1        456
233      555
232233   32323
```

Is it possible in notepad++/sed/vim?

Comment: `!column -t` from command line mode will re-arrange... not necessarily maintain the number of spaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with vim:

```
:%s:\v^(\d+)\s*(\d+):\=printf("%-9d %-d",submatch(1),submatch(2)):
```

Comment: it should be  ...submatch(1),submatch(2)..., right?

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, here is a simple way by using Vim's [Tabular plugin](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular):

```
:Tabu /\w\+
```

Answer (score 1):

For alignment, there are three well-known plugins:

- the venerable [Align - Help folks to align text, eqns, declarations, tables, etc](http://www.vim.org/script.php?script_id=294)
- the modern [tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular)
- the contender [vim-easy-align](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4520)